# Clear shell and crosh histories in Chrome OS

Tags: linux, chrome-os, chrome-book

I have a Acer Chromebook 14 and have installed and removed a whole host of Linux OSes using the crouton installer. As a result, both the crosh and shell histories are jam-packed full of commands I've used in the past.

Short of powerwashing the OS, is there a way to clear the history for both of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have been able to find the files yourself with just a little bit of knowledge about the terminal. I just entered `find -iname "*history*"` from within `shell` and got the solution.

There are two files: `.bash_history` and `.crosh_history`

While `shell` gives you access to a bash shell using the chronos user it is not changing the directory. The prompt says `/` which means you are in the root directory, not to be confused with `/root/`. Just enter `cd` to switch to the users home directory (`/home/chronos/user` in this case), notice that the prompt changed from `/` to `~`.

You can use `rm filename` to delete both files or use `vi filename` to edit the files. `dd` deletes a line in vi, `5dd` deletes 5 lines, `:q!` exits [**vi**](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) without saving `:wq` saves modifications to a file and exits.

Comment: I'll try this tonight and see if it works - thanks!

Comment: It's worked - thanks for the detailed instructions!